# Page rendering time for thick client / desktop C++ application

Tags: performance

Does anyone know how to measure the Page rendering time for thick client / desktop C++ application? also let me know which tool can be used for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a speed index for the app; try using nodejs SpeedLine as an example. The math isn't super hard.

Are there any UI elements exposed which you can query? I'm thinking TestStack.White here, or CodedUI